# Codestyle in SonarQube

Tags: php, sonarqube

We are using SonarQube for analyzing an Symfony Project.

In the IDE(PHPSTORM) we setup a predefined Codestyle (PSR2) and the same in SonarQube.

SonarQube complains about the following code style and says: "Align all arguments in this list at column "16".", right after $error.

```
        $error = json_encode('some Error');
        $response = new Response(
          $error,
          Response::HTTP_OK,
          ['content-type' => 'application/json']
        );
```

What's wrong with the style in this function?

Comment: Coding style questions are not on topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got this issue because [PSR2 states that](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/):

> Code MUST use 4 spaces for indenting

Your code currently uses 2 spaces for indenting.

Comment: Yes, that's what PHPSTORM renders, when you choose PSR-1/PSR-2 as predefined code style. I'll discuss this matter in their community and acceppt your answer here. Thanks.